# Query using references to cell

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I have a table with latitude and longitudes. I want to pull weather data from an API (openweathermap.org) using the coordinates from my table. Any help would be appreciated. I don't have much experience with queries.

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=49.57&lon=-121.79&appid=xxxxx"))
in
    Source
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API call should contain "https://" in the web address like so:

```
https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=49.57&lon=-121.79&appid=xxxxx
```

Also you might already be aware, but it also goes without saying you need to replace XXXXX with your actual appid